# MySQL count 2 different columns both related to one id

Tags: mysql

I have some users like user 10, 20 and 30; and the may be registered on column a or column b;
I need to count how many rows on column a are on each user (simple count() ) but I also want to count how many rows are on the same user but on column b;
my challenge is that I have different users in columns a and b on same row.

```
+----+----+------+------+
| id | a  | b    | c    |
+----+----+------+------+
|  1 | 10 | NULL | NULL |
|  2 | 10 |   20 | NULL |
|  3 | 20 | NULL | NULL |
|  4 | 10 |   30 | NULL |
|  5 | 20 | NULL | NULL |
|  6 | 30 |   20 | NULL |
|  7 | 10 |   20 | NULL |
+----+----+------+------+
```

I have tried:

```
select a, count(if(a is not null,1,null)) aC, count(if(b is not null, 1, null)) bC 
from test 
group by a;
```

but it returns on column b if is not null:

```
+----+----+----+
| a  | aC | bC |
+----+----+----+
| 10 |  4 |  3 |
| 20 |  2 |  0 |
| 30 |  1 |  1 |
+----+----+----+
```

what I need is

```
+----+----+----+
| a  | aC | bC |
+----+----+----+
| 10 |  4 |  0 |
| 20 |  2 |  3 |
| 30 |  1 |  1 |
+----+----+----+
```

I have managed to get the result with a nested select with a where, but only works if I query for a specific user (only one row as result).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way :

```
select a 
    , count(case when col ='A' then 1 end) Acount
    , count(case when col ='B' then 1 end) BCount
from (
   select a , 'A' col
   from tablename
   union all 
   select b , 'B'
   from tablename 
) t 
group by a
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, that *may* indicate a bad design...

What you can try is to use derived tables here. First you need one with all users using a `UNION` over all `a`'s and `b`'s (if you have a table storing all users you can use that instead). Then left join two derived tables doing the aggregation group by `a` or `b` respectively.

```
SELECT u.user,
       coalesce(a.count, 0) AS ac,
       coalesce(b.count, 0) AS bc
       FROM (SELECT a AS user
                    FROM test
             UNION
             SELECT b AS user
                    FROM test) u
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT a AS user,
                              count(*) AS count
                              FROM test
                              GROUP BY a) a
                      ON a.user = u.user
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT b AS user,
                              count(*) AS count
                              FROM test
                              GROUP BY b) b
                      ON b.user = u.user;
```

Comment: yes, it was a bad design, it was made for a student with no supervision, but it has been in production for over a year and now they are complaning about slowness. I am just reducing the querys because they were a select and then a foreach on each row wich has an other select query on each row connecting several times to the DB to get 1 chart info